# Retrieve session data in blades

Tags: laravel

I would like to create a multi step form with validations, but the values are not stored in the inputs through the sessions.

In the controller I have:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

My code at the moment is this:

```
public function addItemStep1(Request $request)
{
    $product = $request->session()->get('product');
        
    return view('admin.items.add', compact('product'))->with([
        'page_name' => __('Add Item')
    ]);
}
    
public function storeNewItemStep1(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);

    if(empty($request->session()->get('product')))
    {
        $product = new Items();
        $product->fill($validatedData);
        $request->session()->put('product', $product);
    } else {    
        $product = $request->session()->get('product');
        $product->fill($validatedData);
        $request->session()->put('product', $product);
    }
        
    return redirect('/');

}
```

The validations work, everything is ok, but unfortunately after sending the form the data just entered does not appear.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ Session::get('title') }}" name="title">
```

Comment: `Session::get('title')` where do you set `title` in a session?

Comment: I'm not very practical, what should I do? In this first step I have two inputs, title and body.